# Entity framework, unit of work and the order of generated inserts statements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, unit-of-work

I'm having a problem where I'm adding objects to the underlying persistence store (MS SQL Server 2012) using the repository and unit of work patterns. The problem is that once committed, the order of the insert statements generated comes in the wrong order and thus they fail due to foreign key constraints.

Imagine that we want to create a customer, address, account and order with order lines in one go (a single commit):

```
using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
    var address = new Address(...);
    _addressRepository.Add(address);

    var customer = new Customer(...);
    customer.AssignLegalAddress(address.Id);
    _customerRepository.Add(customer);

    var account = new Account(..., customer.Id);
    _accountRepository.Add(account);

    var order = new Order();
    order.AssignBuyerAccount(account.Id);
    order.AddOrderLine(...);
    order.AddOrderLine(...);

    _orderRepository.Add(order);

    _unitOfWork.Commit();
    tx.Complete();
}
```

So in order for the Customer to be committed, the address should be committed first, and the customer before the account, and finally the account before the order. So the order in which I call Add on the different repositories.

The repositories above uses Entity Framework 5.0 code first below, and each add operation comes down to adding the entity to the underlying DbContext. We could translate it to: `DbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity)`.
The call to Commit basically calls DbContext.SaveChanges().

The problem is that EF does not seem to care in which order they were added.
While monitoring the queries sent to the underlying store on Commit, I see that first the address is created, so far so good, but then the insert statement to create the account is executed. This fails because the customer haven't been created yet.

Is there a way to make EF take the order in which they we're added into account while saving changes? Otherwise I would have to commit the changes manually, such as:

```
using (var tx = new TransactionScope())
{
    var address = new Address(...);
    _addressRepository.Add(address);

    _unitOfWork.Commit();

    var customer = new Customer(...);
    customer.AssignLegalAddress(address.Id);
    _customerRepository.Add(customer);

    _unitOfWork.Commit();

    var account = new Account(..., customer.Id);
    _accountRepository.Add(account);

    _unitOfWork.Commit();

    var order = new Order();
    order.AssignBuyerAccount(account.Id);
    order.AddOrderLine(...);
    order.AddOrderLine(...);

    _orderRepository.Add(order);

    _unitOfWork.Commit();
    tx.Complete();
}
```

But that hardly seems like a optimal solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inserting entities, then EF will insert whole graph.

```
// Build graph
var customer = new Customer(...);
customer.LegalAddress = new Address(...);
var account = new Account();
account.Customer = customer;
var order = new Order();
order.BuyerAccount = account;
// Here all Navigation properties updated
// and state of all entities set to Added
_orderRepository.Add(order); 
// Here all entities inserted in transaction, PK and FK updated
context.SaveChanges();
```

Complexity begins when you need to insert only part of graph. Then you should manually set state of entities in graph.

Comment: That would only work if there are independent associations between the entities, I believe?

Comment: @TommyJakobsen what do you mean by *independent associations*? Read about relationships in EF http://stackoverflow.com/a/15221140/470005

Comment: As they are described by the EF team [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/05/07/foreign-key-association-in-entity-framework-4.aspx). Navigation properties.

Comment: @TommyJakobsen just one question - have you tried to run code above?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I haven't tried it, but I'm sure that it will work. I do however not have these navigation properties on my model, and I don't want them there. I'm interested in solving my problem using only independent associations/foreign key mappings.

Comment: @TommyJakobsen if you don't have navigation properties, then you can only manually set id's for foreign key fields. EF will not do that work for you. So, you should commit each entity, get it's id, and set that id as FK for other entity.

Comment: That is only the case for database generated ID. In this case I'm assigning the ID's manually.